# Why do I have status 200 and stderr while the web page runs fine? (nginx + passenger + sinatra)

Tags: nginx, sinatra

I am testing my server with a very simple sinatra app:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

# set utf-8 for outgoing
before do
    headers 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
end

get '/test' do
    "test"
end
```

Accessing the app page I can see "test" string displayed but in the meanwhile I found some  error message in nginx's error.log:

```
[ 2013-04-29 21:04:31.9397 17834/7f25f9b25700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1137 ]: [App 17875 stderr] *<my IP>* - 
- [29/Apr/2013 21:04:31] "GET /test " 200 4 0.0021
[ 2013-04-29 21:04:32.5030 17834/7f25f9b25700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1137 ]: [App 17875 stderr] *<my IP>* - 
- [29/Apr/2013 21:04:32] "GET /favicon.ico " 404 18 0.0014
```

I don't have favicon.ico so the last 404 error seems correct, but I don't know what the first error means. Is that caused by the favicon.ico error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error. 200 is a HTTP status code.

Meaning:
200 OK—The request has succeeded. This is the generic success case, and most
successful responses use this code.

Check this link for more information about HTTP status codes: [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Thanks @MMeersseman :) I was wondering why the 200 status logged in nginx's `errors.log` file, also it started with `[App stderr]` tag which scared me. Thanks for the explanation I am going ignore it for now.

Comment: I found an explanation about logging status 200 to `errors.log`, (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sinatrarb/lwd419mimJA) . @MMeersseman, you are right, it seems to be sinatra's behavior which logs everything to stderr.